# nginx proxy s3 bucket SignatureDoesNotMatch issue

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

When I use Nginx to proxy s3 bucket, I get the issue below:

SignatureDoesNotMatch

My configuration looks like this:

```
location  ~ ([^/]+) {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass https://$1.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:801/bucketname/xxx/xxx' 
--header 'X-Amz-Content-SHA256: x' \xx
--header 'content-type: text/plain' 
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20220627T172129Z' 
--header 'Authorization: xxx'

I'm pretty sure the value of $1 above is correct.

But the strange thing is that when I don't use regular expressions, but directly use prefix matching, the request can return the result normally.

```
location  /bucketname/ {
    proxy_pass https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/;
}
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks!